# Impossible to return to local machine after SSH in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I connect to a server through SSH command in Mac Terminal (Ventura 13.1) with:
`ssh login@serveraddress`

When I want to quit I type `exit`.
I quit the server but I do not return to my local machine.
Instead it shows:

```
exit
Press [Enter] to start a shell
```

[ENTER] send me back to my server.
[CTRL]-C nothing happen.

How can I return to my local machine without having to quit this Terminal tab and open a new one?

[image]

Here what I found in found in `/etc/passwd`: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

[image]

Comment: How do you run de the ssh command?

Comment: I do `ssh login@serveraddress`

Comment: What do you have set as your login shell on the remote machine? Note: Not what shell you seem to find yourself in, but what is set for that account in the remote machine's /etc/passwd or equivalent.

Comment: OK @Spiff I found the file /etc/passwd on my server. What should I search in this file?

Comment: What happens if you actually press <ENTER>, or if you press <CTRL>-C?

Comment: @PierU <ENTER> send me back to my server. <CTRL>-C nothing happen.

Comment: @MiguelBocquier In the `/etc/passwd` of the remote machine, find the line for your account, and see what binary is listed at the end of the line (after the last colon on that line). That's your login shell. If the remote system stores this info elsewhere, then check there (e.g. on macOS, check the Open Directory records for your user). We're looking to see if maybe your account is using some wrapper binary that launches a shell, instead of launching a shell directly.

Comment: @Spiff OK found that in `/etc/passwd`: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`. That seems fine. No?

Comment: (1) If your command is `ssh login@serveraddress` then you should check a line that starts with `login:` (not `root:`) in `/etc/passwd` on the remote side. (2) Does your `ssh` support an escape character? For OpenSSH see the [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS). After typing `exit`Enter you are in a good position to try ~. to disconnect. Does your `ssh` support something like this?